# Getting Older PHP Extensions

Tags: php

It happens that I need the GD, SQLite and a few more extensions for php 5.1. But I can't find out where to get them.

I am using WinBinder to develop some desktop applications for Windows with php. The minimal php 5.1 pack has the winbinder extension only. I need other extensions for enhanced features like image editing or data storage.

Can anybody help? I really need this very much.

PS: I want to get pre-compiled DLLs if posible.

Thanks and Regards,
Masnun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here for your specific version: http://www.php.net/releases/

The 'Windows Binary' link will provide a .zip file containing the ext folder where you will find all standard extensions including php_gd2.dll and the 'Collection of PECL modules...' link will allow you to source additional extensions you may require.

You will still need to enable these in your php.ini as described in other comments.

Hope this helps,

Jason.

Answer (score 0):

### GD Installation

> To enable GD-support configure PHP --with-gd[=DIR], where DIR is the GD base install directory. To use the recommended bundled version of the GD library (which was first bundled in PHP 4.3.0), use the configure option --with-gd. GD library requires libpng and libjpeg to compile.
>
> In Windows, you'll include the GD2 DLL php_gd2.dll as an extension in php.ini. The GD1 DLL php_gd.dll was removed in PHP 4.3.2. Also note that the preferred truecolor image functions, such as imagecreatetruecolor(), require GD2.
>
> Enhance the capabilities of GD to handle more image formats by specifying the --with-XXXX configure switch to your PHP configure line.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php

Comment: I need to know how can I get any extension that will work with php 5.1 . Where do I get the php_gd2.dll ? Will it run with all php5 versions?